# 2012 POLO 1.2 S hatchback service manual?

Tags: vw, repair, polo

Is there an after market service manual for a my new polo? I have already tried haynes but it's not available for my model I need it before I start messing around with the electrics. I want to attempt to fit a keyless entry system with alarm. My dad and my brother in law have one so I feel left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Haynes workshop manual does exist for [this vehicle](https://haynes.co.uk/catalog/car-manuals/car-repair-manuals/volkswagen/vw-polo-2009-2014) now.

[image]